# Plot of Parametric Equation that describes a Lead Screw

Tags: plotting, visualization, parametric-functions

I have a Lead Screw, it looks like this:

[image]

There are two parameters at the moment of buying one: Pitch and Lead
[image]

The Lead Screw that I have has a Lead of 2mm and a Pitch of 2mm, but I find a little bit hard to distinguish the difference between both of them, so, I was thinking, maybe if I plot their curve that the thread generates, I can have a better understanding .. So, the curve that comes in my mind is an helix:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/8}, {t, 0, 12 Pi}]
```

[image]

But, I am not sure about what should I modify in the parametric equation to change the lead and/or pitch .. I am not even sure is an helix is enough to describe it

Comment: Lead and pitch are equal for single-start screw threads.  Multi-start (or multiple start) threads have two or more parallel helices, so the lead is the number of helices times the thread spacing (pitch).

Comment: So, I just need to plot another helix but with a z offset? .. If put a particle fixed above the brass nut, What would be the movement that the particle is going to follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

**n** is associated to the number of starts

**rho** is associated to the lead screw external radius

**delphi** is associated to the tooth thickness

**lambda** is associated to the lead

```
n      = 4;
rho    = 0.5;
delphi = 0.3;
lead   = 1;
lambda = lead/(2 Pi);
colors = {Blue, Red, Green, Yellow, Brown, Black, Cyan, Orange};
gr0    = Table[ParametricPlot3D[{rho Cos[t + 2 Pi k/n], rho Sin[t + 2 Pi k/n], lambda t}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> colors[[k]]], {k, 0, n}];
gr1    = Table[ParametricPlot3D[{rho Cos[t + 2 Pi k/n + delphi], rho Sin[t + 2 Pi k/n + delphi], lambda t}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> colors[[k]]], {k, 0, n}];
Show[gr0, gr1]
```

Comment: How do I plot every start with a different color?

Comment: I am trying to do this, but it is not working: `n = 4;
rho = 1.0;
delphi = 0.5;
lambda = 1/3;
gr0 = Table[
   ParametricPlot3D[{If[k < 2, rho Cos[t + 2 Pi k/n], 
      rho Sin[t + 2 Pi k/n], lambda t], 
     If[k > 2, rho Cos[t + 2 Pi k/n], rho Sin[t + 2 Pi k/n], 
      lambda t]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}], {k, 0, 
    n}];
Show[gr0]`

Comment: Included an option to provide personalized colors for each tooth.

Comment: Thanks, just one question more, I don't see the relationship between 1mm and 1/6, How is it related lambda with the lead?

Comment: Introduced also **lambda = lead/(2 Pi);**